SQL / Apache Superset Database - Help w/ Joining my data
So the database is based off Apache superset from what I understand. I am ONLY allowed to "run select statements", so no data manipulation of any kind (EX: I can't run UNION statements to try and merge the data in a different manner). I also have no access to editing/altering the databases themselves. I can simply query the data in this web-based application and that is all I can do.
My question is this; How can I get the below code to avoid duplicative data pulling into my query.

SELECT 
concat(opentripview.locid,'_',opentripview.assettype) AS Key,
opentripview.locid AS GLID,
opentripview.assettype AS Material,
SUM(opentripview.tripdays) AS OpenTripDays, 
COUNT(opentripview.tripdays) AS OpenTripCount, 
SUM(closedtripview.tripdays) AS ClosedTripDays, 
COUNT(closedtripview.tripdays) AS ClosedTripCount 

FROM opentripview 

INNER JOIN closedtripview

ON concat(opentripview.locid,'_',opentripview.assettype)
=concat(closedtripview.locid,'_',closedtripview.assettype)
AND opentripview.assettype=closedtripview.assettype
AND opentripview.locid=closedtripview.locid

WHERE (opentripview.assettype like '%828' or opentripview.assettype like '%24024')

AND opentripview.locid='1000094424'

AND opentripview.division='PA'

AND closedtripview.TripStartDate < DATE '2024-05-01'
AND closedtripview.TripEndDate >= DATE '2024-02-01'
AND closedtripview.TripEndDate < DATE '2024-05-01'

GROUP BY      concat(opentripview.locid,'_',opentripview.assettype),
opentripview.locid,opentripview.assettype;


My original data looks like this (but I have thousands of lines per glid/material...

Key     GLID          Material     OTD     OTC     CTD     CTC
X_X     1000094424    828          1000    10      0       0
X_X     1000094424    828          2000    20      0       0
X_X     1000094424    828          0       0       500     10
X_X     1000094424    828          0       0       750     10


... I end up getting data similar to this...

Key     GLID          Material     OTD     OTC     CTD     CTC
X_X     1000094424    828          9000    90      3750    60


...and I don't really have anything to make a "key" unless I concatenate data. However, even with a concat it seems to be creating roughly 46x the data that I actually need to see (FYI, the 46x is not shown above, but that's what it ends up totaling to when I am looking at my entire dataset). I know all of my filtering and grouping is working as intended because if I run the above without the join, I get the correct totals for both my open and closed data. Based off the above, it seems to be replicating the open trip data for every line of closed trip, which in turn causes the immense number of duplicates. I have also tried all other JOIN statements (R, L, Inner, ETC.), but that changes nothing within my data either. I do also believe that a FULL JOIN is what I need, because there are some GLIDs within the open trip data that will not be in the closed trip data, but I still need those open trips to pull through with "0" as their values in that scenario.
I originally thought a UNION would work better here so I could apply the filters to each of the SELECT statements rather than applying them to all of the query, but my database does not allow UNIONs.
Am I missing something obvious within my JOIN statement, or will I not be able to pull both my open and closed trip data into one query since I do not have specific enough data for a proper key?
Any help is greatly appreciated!
If you look at the above, you will see everything I tried and expected in detail.

add proper example with expected output to understand your question easily

how is the example under the code not "proper"?  How exactly should I be showing an example other than the way I included? First time poster so I am not sure how my example will not suffice!

Go to db<>fiddle and add your sample code like: table creation and other sample example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ @DustinPerini

I've never used dbfiddle either and it's not really helping me figure anything out. Can you just explain what you mean as if I am a SQL newbie (which I am) rather than vaguely pointing me in a direction that is just going to confuse me more?

please follow the article for better understanding db related posting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Apache Superset provides an interface to query your data warehouse but the actual SQL syntax you will use depends on that warehouse.  E.g., the data warehouse is on a PostgreSQL server, you'll use PostgreSQL syntax. Sharing so you know your searches would be "how do I do X in PostgreSQL/Snowflake/SQL Server" etc. not "how do I do X in Superset."
